# Is there a way of displaying X3D models in Eclipse without using Xj3D

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there's a way of displaying X3D models within my java application without having to use Xj3D. The program that I'm using to do the java programming is eclipse. If there is a way of showing the X3D models within eclipse, I would love to know, thanks :)

Comment: What code do you have? [so] isn't a code writing service, please show your code.

Comment: The code that I have is to display the user interface, I've been looking and I've been told that if I use Xj3D then I need the .jars folder and then to import it and I know what I'm doing to import it, just cant find the correct .jars folder with all the files in

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from the comments, the reason why you don't want to use Xj3D is that you can't find the JARs you need to import. Well, in fact, **you don't need to find them manually**, Maven does a good job on that.

**What you need to do:**

1. Right-click your project in Eclipse, and select "Configure -> Convert to Maven Project". You can let the group ID, the artifact ID and all that stuff in the popup the way it is. It only matters if you publish it on Maven yourself, and what you want is to use Maven for pulling dependencies.
2. Double-click the generated `pom.xml`, which will open a menu view first. At the bottom of the editor sub-window, which is now filled with the menu view, there are several tabs. Select the "pom.xml" tab.
3. Below the lines saying

   ```
   <plugins>
   ...
   </plugins>
   ```

   , paste in the following:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.j3d</groupId>
       <artifactId>j3dtools</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
4. You might need to right-click your project and select "Maven -> Update Project..." (also avaliable via the shortcut Alt+F5). Just press OK in the dialogue.
5. There you go! You now have Xj3D available in your project.

The only actual drawback is that Maven (which, of course, needs internet) shows an instable compatibility with proxies. There are setups to handle that (using transparent intermediate proxies), explaining which is not relevant here.

(Not sure if this counts as an answer, because it addresses the problem behind the question rather than the question itself, but it should get things working.)